# Debugging in interactive gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

I have a plot script that doesn't work in some cases. How can I use the interactive mode of gnuplot to debug user defined functions, i.e. just call them with some literal argument to see if they are evaluated correctly?

On a similar note, is there a way to make gnuplot verbose when processing a script?

Answer (score 1):

I managed to find how to test functions or values in interactive gnuplot, there is a handy `print`. You use it like this:

```
print myFunction(1)
```

I still don't know how to run gnuplot in a verbose mode, anyone?

Comment: @Schorsch, it does answer the main part of my original question (in my opinion at least). It certainly doesn't answer the last bit.

Comment: I trying to wrap my mind around *make gnuplot verbose when processing a script* - can you clarify that a bit, please?

Comment: @Schorsch - I would guess, something like `set -x` for `bash`, which will cause every line in the script to be printed to terminal. Right now, I just got an "_Error: May not be a PDF file (continuing anyway)_" from a 800+ line `gnuplot` script - and I have absolutely no idea where it comes from; only thing I can do is "brute-force" comment code sections .... There seems to be a [Info: (gnuplot) debug](http://lavica.fesb.hr/cgi-bin/info2html?(gnuplot)debug) terminal in newer `gnuplot`s, but not in my 4.6 - though I cannot tell what it does...